# php Insert to db where another column contains some words

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a new question cause i didnt find it anywhere. 
I have a db which contains 4 columns. I did my bot to insert array to a column.Now i have to fill another columns.

My filled column contains site links. Exmp: www.dizipub.com/person-of-interest-1-sezon-2-bolum-izle
I need to take "person-of-ınterest" part and write it to another column as kind of a "Person of Interest". And also "1-sezon-2-bolum" as "Sezon 1 - Bölüm 1".

I couldnt find it to do with php not sql. I need to make it with bot. Can someone help me about it please.

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eRzq.jpg)

There is a column named bolumlink where i put the links. As i told i need to take some words from these links. For instance: 
dizi column needs to be filled with "Pretty Little Liars" in first 9 row.

Comment: what do you mean `to do with php not sql`? when you are asking to insert data? Or are you asking about `str_replace()` of PHP?

Comment: im asking about insert data. I mean on that i need to do it with php codes. Not using sql codes on db. it is not very important statementi need to do this with php this part is important for me :)

Comment: Ah, I think you are asking to do this without using **stored procedure**, right?

Comment: thanks a lot @FrozenFire :) i forgot that name. Yes that is exactly what i mean :)

Comment: What methods have you tried? Can you post your code?

Comment: i dont know any method about this and i cant try anything :)  but i know that i cant do this with simple insert methods :) i couldnt find any resources to help me. I dont have any code about this situation.

Comment: Please edit your question: 1) Add your database structure, 2) show expected output, 3) Add code you've tried (simple select and insert will be fine.). Without these I don't know where to start answering your question.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: `update your_table set dizi = 'Pretty Little Liars' where bolumlink LIKE '%pretty-little-liars%'`

Comment: thanks a lot :) but i have lots of data like this. can i set a variable instead of pretty-little-liars ? like %$name% ?

Comment: Is that worked?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by SQL **Update** with **[Like](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html)** which allows you to select rows with pattern based search using wild-cards:

> - % matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
> - _ matches exactly one character.

```
update your_table set dizi = 'Pretty Little Liars' where bolumlink like '%pretty-little-liars%'
```

**NOTE:**

Updating your database using **like** without limit or conditions with unique columns can be dangerous. This code might affect the whole table if empty string is passed.

Comment: thanks i will try to use variable arrays to set it up i will write here the result :)